# Editing EJS templates (express.js, underscore.js, can.js)

Tags: express, underscore.js, backbone-views, ejs

What IDE do you use to edit EJS templates which are standard templating languages for example for can.js, express.js, underscore.js

I'm waiting for supporting EJS in JetBrains WebStorm IDE (BTW who are interested may vote http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-6800)

I wonder is there other IDEs supporting syntax?

Comment: vim works well for me. i don't know if you can call that an ide though.

Answer (score 3):

as a workaround you can get Jetbrains to associate .ejs files with html by using the settings menu.

File->Settings->File Types->Recognized File Types { Look for HTML and add *.ejs in the section for registered patterns}

Comment: =) hope JetBrains will soon add this feature in WebStorm 7 EAP.

Answer (score 2):

The plugin is already there :

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-679#comment=27-1516987

> Martin Möhwald  14 Jul 2016, 03:30
>   I solved the issue with Underscore.js templates being marked with errors and not having correct syntax highlighting the following way:
>    Installed EJS plugin (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7296?pr=)
>    Configured Settings -> Editor -> File Types -> EJS -> Added registered file pattern: *.tmpl (yours can be different I guess)
>    Tada! Nice syntax highlighting without errors :)
>
> Note: I'm using Underscore.js (lodash) templates in a Backbone.js environment. The templates are always separate files of type *.tmpl

Answer (score 1):

it is not integrated but online, but there's Architect http://rowno.github.io/architect/